# SSIS type 2 SCD

Tags: ssis, etl, data-warehouse

I have a fact and dimension tables, fact is 3NF table.

My fact table:

[image]

My Dimension table(total 250 rows, unique ids):

[image]

SCD on SSIS:

[image]

When fact's a metascore changed, i want to change dimension's metascore value of related id.
When i execute ssis, scd component overwrites my dimension 250 rows to 1519 rows(fact's row amount) or doesn't detect changed rows, can you help me doing scd type 2-3? i worked a lot but cant do it...

Comment: I advise doing these activites using T-SQL, not SSIS. In my opinion the SSIS slowly changing dimension component is a travesty. It's not maintainable. It does a destructive edit. Every time you change something it regenerates everything so you better hope you go it right. It's performance is terrible (although not for 250 rows)

Comment: Thank you, i listened your advise at type 3 scd, it works fine... @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Your fact table seems to be full of descriptive labels that should be in dimension tables. To repeat another question, why are you holding metascore in 2 places? Your fact table seems to have an fk to actor - so how are you handling the fact that a film has multiple actors?

Answer (score 0):

Why does the dimension change by the metascore value of the fact table?
Sounds more like a 1:1 relationship.

Comment: Sorry im updating the dimension

Comment: i updated to my current dimension @KrisKul